# A good softphone for OS X

Tags: mac, voip, softphone

I'm sorting out a VOIP setup for the office that I work in (there's about 50 people, mostly macs), and I'm looking for a good SIP softphone that would work with an Asterisk based PBX, and I figured others might be looking for something like this too.

I'm after the usual staples:

- handling multiple sip accounts
- conference calling
- caller id
- ldap/address book integration
- uses SIP

It looks like [Counterpath's x-lite softphones](http://www.counterpath.com/softphone-products.html) are the most popular choices, but I've also seen [Telephone](http://code.google.com/p/telephone/), which is free, but fairly light on features.

What do you guys use?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.nimbuzz.com

Answer (score 0):

[sipgate.com](http://www.sipgate.com/) Used it for a few years.

I was looking at changing over to something like [OpenVBX](http://www.twilio.com/api/openvbx)